# Ignore Code first migrations for integration tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, integration-testing

I want to write my first Integration Test for my `EF code first` project, using `VS2013` and `SqlServer CE`, so defined following `TestInitialize` method in my test project, to delete the old Test DB and recreate a new DB each time that test run:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetupTest()
{
    // file path of the database to create
    var filePath = @"C:\code\TestingEf\TestTemp\RealMyAppDb.sdf";
    // delete it if it already exists
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        File.Delete(filePath);

    // create the SQL CE connection string - this just points to the file path
    string connectionString = "Datasource = " + filePath;

    // NEED TO SET THIS TO MAKE DATABASE CREATION WORK WITH SQL CE!!!
    Database.DefaultConnectionFactory =
       new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");

    using (var context = new IASCoDbContext(connectionString,new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<IASCoDbContext>()))
        {
            // this will create the database with the schema from the Entity Model
            try
            {
                context.Database.Create();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        // initialise our DbContext class with the SQL CE connection string, 
        // ready for our tests to use it.
}
```

but when code reach to `context.Database.Create();` line, I get the following Error:

> {"The specified table does not exist. [ TableName]"}
>   I debugged the test and found that it is because of the program wants to run `Migrations` `UP()` method.

**[Updated]**

the following code contains constructors of my `IADCoDbContext`:

```
public class IASCoDbContext : BaseDbContext
{
    static IASCoDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<IASCoDbContext>(null);
    }

    public IASCoDbContext(string connectionString)
       : base("name=ERPContext")
    {
    }

    public IASCoDbContext(string connectionString, IDatabaseInitializer<IASCoDbContext> initializer)
        :base(connectionString)
    {

        Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
    }
    ...
}
```

and this is my `BaseDbContext`:

```
public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseDbContext()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public BaseDbContext(string context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

Is it any way that I disable `Code First Migration` for my integration tests?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the migrations are executed by a Database Initializer which can be disabled by setting the Initializer for your DbContext to null.

```
Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(null);
```

Without knowing the code in the IASCoDbContext constructor I can only guess what’s happening but as

```
DropCreateDatabaseAlways<IASCoDbContext>()
```

is also a Database Initializer which basically does this

```
public virtual void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
{
    Check.NotNull<TContext>(context, "context");
    context.Database.Delete();
    context.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState.DoesNotExist);
    this.Seed(context);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I assume this InitializeDatabase Method is called in the Constructor of your context.
So i think the

```
context.Database.Create();
```

method call is redundant.

But as I said without knowing what happens within the Context Constructor with the DatabaseInitializer passed as a parameter it’s just guessing.

Comment: Ok as i said, the context.Database.Create is redundant. Just use the Context constructor without the initilizer IASCoDbContext(string connectionString) and it should work.

Comment: Mayby it’s a usefull information for you that the context.Database.Create() method also uses Migrations to create the DB when available.

Comment: You are correct,  `context.Database.Create()` uses Migrations to create the DB when available, I want each time my tests run the DB deletes and recreate without using Migrations. If I remove `context.Database.Create()` and use the Context constructor without the initializer, I get this error: `{"The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = C:\\code\\TestingEf\\TestTemp\\RealMyAppDb.sdf ]"}`.

Comment: You cannot remove both. Either use the DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer or the `context.Database.Create()` method. If Migrations exist they will be used to create the DB. All the code where this decision is made is internal. Why don’t you want the Migrations to be executed? There might be some different behavior if the DB is created from the Model only compared to a creation by the migrations. (e.g. unique index,…)

Comment: I renamed a column in my model, when I run my test I got following error: "Assert.Fail failed. Error occured in Db creationDirect column renaming is not supported by SQL Server Compact. To rename a column in SQL Server Compact, you will need to recreate it."

Comment: That is not directly related to the original question, is it? SQL Compact simply cannot perform a rename operation. delete and rebuild your migrations or if you have an existin DB you want to update Change RenameColumn to AddColumn, Copy-Data, DropColumn.

Comment: One of my migrations step wants to rename a column in Database, and this cause above error, so I want to ignore migrations.

Comment: You cannot "ignore the migrations". As soon as they exist, context.Database.Create uses them for the initial DB Creation. If you want to use SQL Compact für your Integration Tests avoid RenameColumn Migrations or Switch to LocalDB.